# Creating a merge of two directories using symlink on Windows

Tags: windows, symlink

Is it possible to combine two separate directories into the same place on Windows using symbolic links?

Something like this:

```
mklink /J c:\Merged c:\Data\Dir1
mklink /J c:\Merged c:\Data\Dir2
```

Which doesn't actually work because C:\Merged cannot be created twice.

Or maybe there is an alternative way of dong this other than symlinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how symbolic links work.
(So the answer to your question is "No", at least not with symbolic links.)

What you are looking for is called a [Union Mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) - I'm not aware of any way to accomplish this on Windows, though it may be possible and I've just never seen it...

Comment: Nope, not possible with anything built-in to Windows.

Comment: @longneck I don't think there's anything third-party either - it would be some pretty nasty filesystem hackery and I don't know anyone who would want to take that on in the Windows world...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think it safe to assume it is not possible then.